# Google App Engine: KindError - No implementation for kind 'ObjectName'

Tags: google-app-engine, model

I'm writing a db.Model class in google app engine that looks something like this:

```
class Cheese(db.Model):
   name = db.StringProperty()
   def say_cheese(self):
      return name + "cheese"
```

For some reason, whenever I run:

```
cheese = Cheese(name = "smelly")
print thing.say_cheese()
```

I get a KindError - No implementation for kind 'Cheese'. I want it to say: "smelly cheese"

Am I doing something wrong? Am I not allowed to add a method to a db.Model object?

Comment: The code you posted has a few problems: 1) `say_cheese` tries to access `name` where I think you mean `self.name`.  2) `thing` is used without being defined.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds like `thing` is actually being loaded from a `db.ReferenceProperty()` field (on a non-`Cheese` entity) which happens to be referring to a `Cheese` entity.  If you access such a property without first importing the `Cheese` model then the code won't be able to find the `Cheese` kind to construct the entity and will fail with the error you indicated.

Anyway, try importing the `Cheese` model in the code which is causing the error.  Then the code should be able to find the implementation for `Cheese` when it needs it.

To answer the other part of your question: Yes, you are certainly allowed to add your own methods to a `db.Model` subclass.

Comment: Cool, it works. I also had another strange problem where two modules were cross-importing each other, but I got that fixed as well.